# How to create HearthStone Graphic

Tags: photoshop-effects

[image]

is this graphic rendered in 3d or created by Photoshop using bevel and other things..?
if with bevel then how can i add curved in effect?

Comment: Which "curved effect" are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I am almost certain those are 3D objects.

Reason? Hearthstone is running on Unity, pretty much everything in Hearthstone can glitch out because of that. Almost everything you can see in Hearthstone is an object. When you click something in Hearthstone, it will always hit the right thing, because it's not exactly a flat graphic with variable coordinates.

You can surely easily recreate those graphics though with a little bit of time. As you mentioned in your post

> how can i add curved in effect?

You can do this using the "Inner Shadow" Layer Style.
Just right click your layer, go to layer styles, and Inner Shadow, play around with the settings a bit. It's not that hard.

If you want to make more than one, I'd advise you to use the "Global Light" setting so your graphics look uniformly.